# IIS 7.5 = Nested web.config will not override custom error handling set in application level web.config

Tags: iis, coldfusion

Running ColdFusion 11 (Update 7) and IIS 7.5

My site application/root level web.config:

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

My nested web.config file, which sits inside /api/eb :

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

When I visit a page that sits within the /api/eb sub-directory (e.g. 401.cfm) and trigger a 401 status code the server will return the Custom error handler response. My interpretation from the docs is that the nested web.config file should override the root web.config file but it clearly is not.

I've checked within the IIS applicationhost file and httpErrors overrideModeDefault is set to true. I also tried using a location tag within my root web.config file to do the same thing but it is also ignored unless I set the path to the wildcard character.

I'm out of ideas. Your help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found this article which seems to explain your question pretty well - [How to Use HTTP Detailed Errors in IIS 7.0](http://www.iis.net/learn/troubleshoot/diagnosing-http-errors/how-to-use-http-detailed-errors-in-iis)

Specifically this excerpt:

> **Security Considerations**
>
> A word of caution: For architectural reasons, IIS can only execute the URL if it is located in the same Application Pool. Use the redirect feature to execute a Custom Error in a different Application Pool.
>
> IIS can also return a 302 Redirect to the browser when a particular error occurs. Redirect is good if you have a server farm. For instance, you can redirect all your errors to a central location that you closely monitor.
>
> There is risk however: `responseMode="File"` (which is the default) allows you to specify every file on the disk. This will not work if you are very security conscious.
>
> A workable scenario might include only allowing the delegation of the errorMode setting. This enables a developer to receive Detailed Errors for his application even if he is using a remote client. All that is necessary is to set `errorMode="Detailed"`. Here is how to configure this scenario:
>
> Allow the delegation of the httpErrors section:
>
> `<section name="httpErrors" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />`
>
> Second, go to the  section in applicationHost.config and change it so that only errorMode is delegated:
>
> `<httpErrors lockAllAttributesExcept="errorMode" lockElements="error">`
>   `<error statusCode="404" prefixLanguageFilePath="E:\inetpub\custerr" path="404.htm" />`
>   `<error statusCode="401" prefixLanguageFilePath="E:\inetpub\custerr" path="401.htm" />`
>   `<error statusCode="403" prefixLanguageFilePath="E:\inetpub\custerr" path="403.htm" />`
>   `<error statusCode="405" prefixLanguageFilePath="E:\inetpub\custerr" path="405.htm" />`
>   `<error statusCode="406" prefixLanguageFilePath="E:\inetpub\custerr" path="406.htm" />`
>   `<error statusCode="412" prefixLanguageFilePath="E:\inetpub\custerr" path="412.htm" />`
>   `<error statusCode="500" prefixLanguageFilePath="E:\inetpub\custerr" path="500.htm" />`
>   `<error statusCode="501" prefixLanguageFilePath="E:\inetpub\custerr" path="501.htm" />`
>   `<error statusCode="502" prefixLanguageFilePath="E:\inetpub\custerr" path="502.htm" />`
>
> `</httpErrors>`

Notice that the correct value for the `overrideModeDefault` attribute is `Allow`, not `true` as you mentioned in your question.

This article further explains the `overrideModeDefault` attribute - [Understanding IIS 7.0 Configuration Delegation](http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/managing-your-configuration-settings/understanding-iis-configuration-delegation#04)

Excerpt:

> The overrideModeDefault attribute is an optional attribute that defines the locked state of a section. Its available values are either Allow or Deny. The default value is "Allow". All IIS sections that are related to any performance, security or critical aspect of the server are locked with this attribute set to "Deny". If the overrideModeDefault attribute is set to "Deny", then any configuration files at a lower level (i.e. web.config files) that set a value for a property for the specific configuration section are not able to take effect and override the global values. This incurs in a lock violation and an error occurs.

Comment: On double checking I can see that I did set overrideModeDefault to allow